Issues With Contact Form 7 Unique ID
I am trying to use the Contact Form 7 id to customize the CSS.
I can use the the .wpcf7 id an it works perfect, registering the CSS. Yet when I try and introduce the designated form id (af8b110) it will not work.
Is this even a functionality? I want to style different forms depending on their page and using .wpcf7 will change all forms. I want to style using their unique id.
So here is the short code I have tried in my hmtl, both work fine when using the id .wpcf7 in my CSS style-sheet
[contact-form-7 id="af8b110" title="Main Contact Form"]

[contact-form-7 id="x" title="Contact form 1" html_id="contact-form-af8b110" html_class="form contact-form"]

When I try and use the actual form id I get nowhere.
I have tried the following
.wpcf7-af8b110

.af8b110


You'll have to look at the front end for the div, as the ID contains wpcf7-form ID- post-id, etc.

May be you can try this class: .wpcf7-form-id-af8b110
To style Contact Form 7 forms using their unique IDs.
